# No puedo crear un pdf con report 10.5 Crystal Report en VS2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

Tengo instalado el paquete de CrystalReport para crear pdf versiones 10.5.3700 y 13.0.3500 en Visual Studio 2017.  El problema que tengo es a la hora de crear pdf con un report de la version 10.5 desde VS2017. En el administrador  de referencias del proyecto con .Net Framework 4.5 en extensiones tenia referenciada la version 13.0 por lo que cambio las referencias a la version 10.5 pero cuando compilo el proyecto. Me salen 2 errores de compilacion:

'CrystalReportViewer' is ambiguous in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions.Web' en Archivo App_Web_gojru2sa.0.vb linea 238

'CrystalReportViewer' is ambiguous in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions.Web' en Archivo preview.aspx linea 130

Si intento compilar el proyecto dejando las referencias con la version 13 tengo una excepcion en la linea con codigo:

```
crs.ReportDocument.Filename = path;
```

CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: El nombre del archivo del informe estaba vacio.

Si desde el editor de VS2017 abro el fichero .rpt y lo vuelvo a grabar me sale un aviso de convertir el rpt a la version actual. Entonces acepto y vuelvo a compilar el programa con las referencias de la version 13 pero me sigue mostrando la misma excepcion en la linea de codigo 'El nombre del archivo del informe estaba vacio' en la misma linea. Si vuelvo a poner las referencias de la version 10.5 me salen los 2 errores iniciales de compilacion.

Este es el codigo:

```
private static void VincularDatosReport(string path, string path2, ref ReportDocument rpt, string Parametro1) {

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
CrystalReportSource crs = new CrystalReportSource();
crs = new CrystalReportSource();

crs.ReportDocument.FileName = path;
crs.ReportDocument.Refresh();

crs.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, Parametro1);
crs.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, Parametro1);

ConnectionInfo conne = new ConnectionInfo();

conne.ServerName = "NombreServidor";
conne.DatabaseName = "NombreBaseDatos";
conne.UserID = "Usuario";
conne.Password = "Password";

TableLogOnInfo tablelogs = new TableLogOnInfo();

Database db = crs.ReportDocument.Database;
Tables tbls = db.Tables;

foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tab in tbls)
    {
        tablelogs = tab.LogOnInfo;
        tablelogs.ConnectionInfo = conne;
        tab.ApplyLogOnInfo(tablelogs);
    }

rpt = crs.ReportDocument;
rpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,"\\MiDocumento.pdf");

}
```

El proyecto lo he generado para .Net Framework 4.5 a partir de "Archivo - Nuevo Proyecto - Sitio web vacío de ASP.NET"

Comment: asegura que en la preview.aspx en el codigo html que este referenciada bien la versión.

Comment: La preview.aspx la crea dinamicamente el compilador, no la creo yo. He probado a cambiar las referencias de la 13.0 a la 10. y luego agregar esta linea en el aspx de html donde llamo a la funcion estatica pero tampoco  funciona: <%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR"%> Me sigue dando el mismo error de compilacion.

Answer (score 0):

Si genero un proyecto nuevo como .Net Framework 4.6.1 "Archivo - Nuevo Proyecto - Sitio de ASP.NET Web Forms" y luego cambio las referencias a version 10.5 entonces compila bien el proyecto y funciona. Pero necesito que funcione el proyecto desde el que comence con .Net Framework 4.5 y a partir de un Sitio web vacío de ASP.NET